# How to Access React Context Inside a WebView in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, react-context

I would like to be able to access React Context inside my WebView but the following error occurs:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context')`

Here is my code:

```js
// App.js

import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export const AppContext = createContext({
    value: '',
    setValue: () => { }
})

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('Hello there')

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
            <WebView source={{ html: renderToString(<WebViewComponent />) }} />
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

```js
// WebViewComponent.js

export default function WebViewComponent() {
    const { value, setValue } = useContext(AppContext)

    return (
        <div>
            {value}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a simple solution to the problem is to just pass anything as the props to `renderToString(<WebViewComponent />)` instead of using context.

So in my example it will be like this:

```js
// App.js

import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('Hello there')

    return (
        <WebView 
            source={{ 
                html: renderToString(<WebViewComponent value={value} setValue={setValue} />) 
            }} 
        />
    )
}
```